# Trying to Implement Onclick event for the first time

Tags: event-tracking

I am trying to track the clicks on a link and the code I have used is this:

```
href="https://mattressfirmnewmexico.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/1.pdf" onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'Coupon Click', 'click', 'Coupon Savings $100 Off');
```

I have set the goal in GA as well, but when I am trying to check if my implemented code is correct or not I cannot see any data in the real-time event section. I can see myself as an active user but there is no data for the event. Attached is the picture if you all can see.

I don't understand where am I going wrong that I am unable to see the real-time  data as well.

I am implementing this for the first time, so any kind of help will be appreciated.

GA Snapshot:

[image]

Comment: You are missing a double quote off the end, is it a typo or cut&paste issue.

Comment: That's already present on the website, I might have missed that to mention here.

Answer (score 0):

You must add the double quote:

```
href="https://mattressfirmnewmexico.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/1.pdf" onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'Coupon Click', 'click', 'Coupon Savings $100 Off');"
```

as [Code Gorilla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/803978/code-gorilla) said

Comment: I didn't make it an answer because I though it can't be that simple :)